# c# Update Cookie, without forcing the user to login

Tags: c#, forms-authentication

I have a 'UI' setting that controls the appearance, which the user can change the setting, however it involves updating the cookie.

I seem to be able to update, but it forces the user to authenticate again, how can i update the cookie without getting the user to autenticate again?

```
//We need to update the userToken as the menuOptionChanged
             var usertoken2 = new UserToken(schedule.MinimisedMenuBool);
             HttpCookie cookie = FormsAuthentication.GetAuthCookie(usertoken.UserName, false);
             var ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(cookie.Value);

             var newticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(ticket.Version,ticket.Name,ticket.IssueDate,ticket.Expiration,false,usertoken2.CalculateRawToken(),ticket.CookiePath);

             // Encrypt the ticket and store it in the cookie
             cookie.Value = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(newticket);
            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Set(cookie);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you saving UI appearance preferences in the authentication cookie?

Is there anything wrong with just saving it as a separate cookie?

```
HttpCookie menuCookie = new HttpCookie("menuCookie");    

menuCookie.Values.Add("menuAppearance", schedule.MinimisedMenuBool);
menuCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1);

Response.Cookies.Add(menuCookie);
```

Then you can optionally only parse that cookie for logged in users.